# Tem como eu declarar uma biblioteca dentro de uma classe em C++?

Tags: c++, string, biblioteca

Preciso utilizar variáveis do tipo `string`, o problema é que eu não consigo incluir bibliotecas dentro das minhas classes no Code::Blocks, tem alguma maneira de incluir a biblioteca `string`/`string.h` na minha classe em C++?

O código da minha classe:

```
#ifndef PROJETO_H
#define PROJETO_H


class projeto
{
private:
    string codprojeto;
    int estprojeto;
    int faseprojeto;
    int funcao;
public:
    projeto();
    bool regcod(string cod);
    string consultarcod();
};

#endif // PROJETO_H
```

Comment: Não entendi direito a sua pergunta! As classes da biblioteca padrão funcionam normalmente no codeblocks; basta você incluir a string.h; já tentou isso? Se sim, que tipo de erro apareceu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Precisa incluir o arquivo com as definição de `string`. Aí pode acessar seus membros. Mas tem que lembrar que o espaço de nomes dele é o `std`, então ou usa o nome completamente qualificado `std::string` ou coloca um `using namespace std` para poder usar o nome simples sem "sobrenome".

```
#ifndef PROJETO_H
#define PROJETO_H

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class projeto {
private:
    string codprojeto;
    int estprojeto;
    int faseprojeto;
    int funcao;
public:
    projeto();
    bool regcod(string cod);
    string consultarcod();
};

#endif // PROJETO_H
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/vP7WQJ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/Includecpp). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/Include2.cpp).

Comment: ow,vlw mano,era isso mesmo,eu não tava conseguindo incluir essa biblioteca,mas agora eu vejo que é porque eu não usei o namespace std,vlws:D